# Exclude folder inside war directory in app engine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have `node_modules` folder inside `war` folder of app engine java project. I do not want to deploy this folder into app engine. So i tried following

```
<static-files>
   <exclude path="/node_modules/" />
</static-files>
```

and

```
<static-files>
   <exclude path="/node_modules/**" />
</static-files>
```

Both does not work. How do i exclude the folder?

Answer (score 1):

Exclude this folder from both *static* **and** *resource* files:

```xml
<static-files>
  ...
  <exclude path="/node_modules/**" />
  ...
</static-files>

<resource-files>
  ...
  <exclude path="/node_modules/**" />
  ...
</resource-files>
```

Answer (score -1):

for .png files try:

```
<static-files>
   <exclude path="/node_modules/**.png" />
</static-files>
```

source https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig?hl=pl&csw=1#Including_and_Excluding_Files

Comment: But i dont have png file in that folder. It has different type of files. I want to exclude that folder(node_modules) itself

Comment: the .png is just an example. Replace them with extension that you have.

Comment: But the folder have different type of files. The folder is only used for build the front end. So i could not specify the extension of the file.

Comment: From the link I give: ' In a pattern, * represents zero or more of any character in a file or directory name, and ** represents zero or more directories in a path'. So try just <exclude path="/node_modules/**" />

Comment: I checked this: <exclude path="/node_modules/*.*" /> and it seems to work

Comment: Sorry, it does not work for me. I placed your code exactly inside static-files tag, nothing more and less.

Comment: which version of app engine sdk do you use?

Comment: I checked on 1.7.0 and 1.8.8 and it works on both if files have extension.

Comment: I uses version 1.7.3. The deployment failed with too may files.

Comment: Try excluding them from resources as well (<resource-files>). All files belong to both static and resource files by default (except .jsp and web-inf files of course). If a file is at least a resource then it has to be deployed.